# Broken Textures in Three.js GLTF export

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping, gltf

I’m having weird issues exporting a model from Three.js and having it appear properly in PowerPoint. When exported to gltf and imported into PowerPoint it looks like this:
[image]

the black areas aren't the issue, its the overlapping faces across the model showing through that are the problem.

I’ve set and unset these flags on the export and nothing changes:

```
let options = {
  binary: true,
  forcePowerOfTwoTextures: true,
  onlyVisible: true,
  embedImages: true,
  forceIndices: true,
}
```

But when i run it through the GLTF online converter by Lewy here: https://blackthread.io/gltf-converter/ with nothing but ‘embeded images’ turned on, it then works in PowerPoint without issue:

[image]

So I'm left wondering whether on his website, because the model is re-generated from the uploaded one, in the process of reading it, it's getting cleaned up by the GLTFLoader?

I’m at a complete dead end as to how to fix this within three.js without using the external uploader/re-exporter :(

**UPDATE:**

Seems to be an issue with alpha blend mode and material being set to transparent. If the blend mode is changed to 'mask' the issue disappears but then textures that have transparency alpha greater than the alphaTest value completely disappear. But this issue is only turning up for models imported to PowerPoint, when i upload to SketchFab it's all fine.

Comment: I'm confused. You're importing your GLTF assets to PowerPoint? If so, what does this have to do with three.js?

Comment: I'm making a mesh in three.js then exporting that mesh to a GLTF. I've dug into the GLTF file and found that setting "alphaMode": "MASK" (turning material.transparent: off) stops solid textures from glitching but then stops semi-transparent textures from displaying in PowerPoint. So it appears to be the way the PowerPoint renderer handles "alphaMode": "BLEND", which SketchFab understands and doesn't have any issue with.